# What goes to RAM, Harddrive, Stack and Heap in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

Could someone tell in general what goes to what (Harddrive,RAM, Stack or Heap) at runtime in C++ for these instances :

- Local/global variables
- Classes, Methods and functions
- Pointers
- Objects

And is Stack/Heap both located in physical RAM?

I would appreciate if someone could include hardware analogy in the answer.
Thanks.

Comment: I smell homework or test preparation :) All of that is OK, as long as the question is tagged appropriately.

Comment: Don't mix up *programming languages* and *computing hardware*. The former is a language, the latter breaks when you drop it on the floor. Programming languages can be used to *instruct* a computer, but they are first and foremost an abstract construction.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: If I could say then where do C++ instruct the computer to put them in the end?

Comment: @Maiss: C++ doesn't do anything. It's a *language*. Your *compiler* creates machine-code instructions for your computer based on a program written in that language.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is generally **dependent on OS**, but it's generally like so:

Everything goes to RAM. The binary resides in the hard-drive, but, when ran, is fully loaded, along with dependent libraries, into RAM.

Stack and heap are implementation details, but they also reside in the RAM.

Although loaded in RAM, the memory is not directly addressable. The operating system allocates virtual memory for each process. This means that the address `0x001` is not actually located at `0x001` in the RAM, but represents an address in virtual address space.

EDIT: Clarification to one of op's comments:

Are binaries fully or partially loaded at runtime? And, are those binaries only accessed once at runtime or continuisly being read from Harddrive?

For example, in MS, if you link against a library, it will be fully loaded at runtime, at the start of the program. If you load it programatically, via `LoadLibrary()`, it is loaded into memory at the function call, and can be unloaded from memory.

Comment: @GuySirton I specified that, but most usually it's RAM.

Comment: I believe his point is that parts of virtual memory - namely pages - can and will be swapped out to the disk.

Comment: Yup. If you're (the op) writing C++ that needs any kind of performance at all, then virtual memory implementation details are very important. Check out this wikipedia page to get started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging

Comment: Could you tell please if Binaries are fully or partially loaded at runtime? And, are those binaries only accessed once at runtime or continuisly being read from Harddrive?

Comment: @Maiss it depends. For example, in MS, if you link against a library, it will be fully loaded at runtime, at the start of the program. If you load it programatically, via `LoadLibrary()`, it is loaded into memory at the function call, and can be unloaded from memory.

Answer (score 9):

All of them go into memory.  Now, the definition of "in memory" depends on the operating system, compiler and linker options, the executable format and a million other factors.

On many modern operating systems, when a process is created, the executable file is mapped into memory (this means a memory region was reserved for the executable but doesn't mean the executable has been loaded in that location yet).

Some OSes will load parts of the executable file as it is accessed (see "delay loading"), which is more common for dynamically loaded libraries (DLLs on Windows, and Shared Objects on UNIX-like systems).  This mostly influences the current "location" of functions, they are either "on disk" as the executable file, or "in memory" if that part of the executable has been mapped.

Variables and all other program data go to memory.  However, any OS that operates with virtual memory may swap all your program's running state (including the stack and heap) to disk at its convenience, and then later restore it back to keep running your program.

In conclusion, all the items on your list (variables, functions, etc.) are in memory, although then may not be stored in "physical RAM" at all times.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, when you save a program, it goes to hard drive, when you start to compile and execute the program it goes to main memory (RAM). All Stack and heap memory is part of the ram memory.

According to the variable declaration in the program and function call the memory is allocated. default stack size is 2 MB(from googling ) and its store all the local variables of your program.

Heap contains all the data, which are created during run time, means through either `malloc` or `new`